# JS Get File Contents?

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I'm creating a new language, with a JavaScript parser, and I'm currently trying to figure out how to get a local file's contents. I tried using a `XMLHttp`request which looked like this:

```
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", "testing.txt", true);
```

But that didn't work. I got this error in my terminal:

```
`(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ^`

ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/source.js:1:81)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:441:10)

`Process exited with code: 1`
```

I know Python can get a file's contents using the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
with open(file, 'r') as myfile:
data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')`
```

So should I just switch over to Python instead? Or is there a way to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this ?

```js
function readFile(evt) {
  var file = (evt.target.files)[0]; 
  var r = new FileReader();
  r.onload = (function(file) {
    return function(e) {
      var contents = e.target.result;
      alert(contents);
    };
  })(file);
  r.readAsText(file);
}
  
document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
```

Comment: I want it to run it on local files though, not an imported one.

Comment: Perfect! 
a more ES6 Version : 
`handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    const r = new FileReader();
    let body;
    r.onload = (file => {
      return e => {
        body = e.target.result;
        this.api.importCSV(body).subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          }, error => console.log(error));
      }})(files.item(0));
    r.readAsText(files.item(0));
  }`